# Geth Chaindata size

Tags: blockchain, mining

I did the blockchain sync from scratch via geth in command line. The current size of the chaindata folder is 68 GB. Is this normal or am I missing something. Also there is a .ethash folder with 66 GB created. I will soon run out of space if this continues. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that Geth is planning to have a pruning function eventually, but it isn't available yet. If you resync from scratch using `--fast` it should reduce the size to around 11GiB. The .ethash folder is used for mining, and it can be deleted if you are not mining. It will be recreated if it is ever needed.

See also [How to reduce chaindata database size?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/how-to-reduce-chaindata-database-size?rq=1)

Update: Geth v1.5.0 includes an option for a light client. This will take your chain data down to under 200MB. Just start geth with the `--light` option. You can then optionally delete the main chain data.

Comment: @VijayNarayanan - To remove your old chain data you can use `geth removedb`. To fast sync, `geth --cache=1024 --fast console` - if you have enough memory. `geth` has been crashing on my virtual server with 4 Gb ram and 4 Gb swap - had to switch to parity.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I did geth --cache=1024 --fast. I deleted the chaindata folder first and then did the above.

Comment: @JordanMack, some stats and observations on the `--light` syncing at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11295/1268 .

Comment: I did geth removedb && getch --fast cache=2048, but I no benifit, still same amount of data