# How does the "block parameter" work with RPC calls? Do light nodes have access to historical data?

Tags: json-rpc, evm, merkle-patricia-tries

I'm looking at the RPC spec. Many calls (`eth_getBalance`, `eth_getStorageAt`) allow for a custom "block parameter" where I can pass in any block number.

How does this work? Does each node maintain a copy of the state for each block (I assume not). Do nodes synced via `--fast` have access to blocks before they were fast synced?

Cheers
-Aakil

Comment: Some info and testing with historical events of `geth --light` at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11295/1268 .